# Как правильно задать очередь отрисовки в Unity3D?

Tags: unity3d

Мой проект выглядит следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стрелками указаны 2 спрайта, в рамке выделены объекты с компонентом Image.
Объекты нужно отрисовать поверх спрайтов.
Проблема: при уменьшении координаты Z или Order in Layer спрайтов они становятся полупрозрачными, тоже самое случается при увеличении этих параметров у объектов - спрайты опять же становятся еле заметными.

Проблему решил просто убрав спрайты и заменив на объекты с компонентом Image, но все равно может кто сталкивался и подскажет из-за чего такое происходит и как исправить?

Comment: >>Объекты нужно отрисовать поверх спрайтов<< Если я правильно понял, и отрисовать надо Image поверх Spite, Есть вариант пошаманить с layer-ами. Выносите отдельные слои, указываете их для ваших объектов и для спрайтов, а уже в очереди отрисовки можете спокойно менять какая из групп будет отрисовываться первой, а какая второй

Answer (score 0):

Для начала бы показал настройки image и sprite. 
А вообще не используй sprite renderer в перемешку с canvas renderer (Т.е. не держи sprite в recttransform, он не заточен под него). Это как UI с GUI использовать(хотя у них больше общего, rect'ы всякие)